# titleLabel can't fit in height correctly in UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

For some reasons, I can't make the titleLabel fit correctly inside UIButton.

Fit in width works, but not in height (which is supposed to work thanks to `baselineAdjustment`)

```
let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (CGFloat(index) * sizePerChar + marginWidthFirstLine / 2), y: marginHeight/2, width: sizePerChar, height: sizePerChar))
btn.setTitle("P", forState: .Normal)
btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
btn.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "KohinoorDevanagari-Regular", size: 150)
btn.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
btn.titleLabel!.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
btn.titleLabel!.baselineAdjustment = .AlignCenters
btn.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center
btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
self.view.addSubview(btn)
```

Here is the result:

The letter m is smaller and fits in width, but all the other letters are way too big in height...

[image]

Comment: It looks like the problem is adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth. The only reason the "m" resizes like that is because its width is longer than its height.  All of the other letters have a smaller width than they do height.  So when they scale to fit the width of your squares, their height scales up too and ends up not fitting.

Comment: Also note that baselineAdjustment property is effective only when the numberOfLines property is set to 1.

Comment: @Shripada It is set to 1 by default and even explicitly, it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

btn.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false

Comment: No it does not. Now the only correct letter (m) doesn't work anymore and the rest stayed the same

Comment: sizePerChar should be width required for the character 'm'.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the height after setting font.

NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:yourButton.titleLabel.font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];

CGSize  size = [@"A Dummy text" sizeWithAttributes:attributes];

yourbutton.frame.size.height = size.height;

Comment: My goal is not to change the height of the button, but the font.

Answer (score 0):

It can be something to do with the font you are using.

```
UIFont(name: "KohinoorDevanagari-Regular", size: 150)
```

Try with systemFont and test if its working .
Other wise it should have worked

Comment: Tried with `systemFontOfSize(150)` it is the same problem. (KohinoorDevanagari-Regular is an official iOS bundled font)